# MySQL Key efficiency zero - how to debug

Tags: python, mysql

My Key efficiency in MySQL is 0.00

[image: MySQL statistic]

I have app in python (using SQL Alchemy) and before this screenshot I added index on most used table.

Here is my (probably) most used function now:

```
def getPredictionRowForPrediction(session, predictor):
    """
    :param session: sesja
    :param predictor: PredictorRow
    :return: None jeśli nie ma już nic do roboty,  PredictionRow oznacza, że ta predykcja jest wzięta
    """
    response = session.query(PredykcjaRow).filter(
        PredykcjaRow.predyktor == predictor,
        PredykcjaRow.czy_wziete == False,
        PredykcjaRow.czy_zrobione == False
    ).first()
    if response is None:
        return None
    response.czy_wziete = True
    try:
        session.commit()
        return response
    except:
        return None
```

@edit:
it produces:

```
SELECT predykcje.fasta_id AS predykcje_fasta_id, predykcje.predyktor AS predykcje_predyktor, predykcje.`ID` AS `predykcje_ID`, predykcje.czy_wziete AS predykcje_czy_wziete, predykcje.czy_zrobione AS predykcje_czy_zrobione  FROM predykcje  WHERE 'foldindex' = predykcje.predyktor AND predykcje.czy_wziete = false AND predykcje.czy_zrobione = false   LIMIT 1
```

and recently added index:

[image]

Comment: what is the type  of predyktor?

Comment: VCHAR(10) and it is foreign key